# KeyErrors while generating a dict

Tags: python

Below is the list of dict using trying to generate dict

```
data = [
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 15), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 16), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 17), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 18), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 19), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 20), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 21), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 18), 'name': u'aj', 'total': 0},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), 'name': u'ap', 'total': 8}, 
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 15), 'name': u'ap', 'total': 8},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 16), 'name': u'ap', 'total': 8},
  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 17), 'name': u'ap', 'total': 8},
  {'name': u'ab', 'l_total': 8, 'type': u'UP'}, 
  {'name': u'ab', 'l_total': 8, 'type': u'PL'},
  {'name': u'fk', 'l_total': 29, 'type': u''},
  {'name': u'jw', 'l_total': 1, 'type': u'PD'}, 
  {'name': u'uk', 'l_total': 16, 'type': u'UP'}, 
  {'name': u'sk', 'l_total': 24, 'type': u'PL'},
  {'name': u'ss', 'l_total': 8, 'type': u'PL'},
  {'name': u'sst', 'l_total': 8, 'type': u'PL'}]



results = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for fetch in data:
        user = fetch['name']
        hrs = fetch['total']
        row = results[user]
        new_y = fetch['type']
        row['new_y'] = fetch['l_total']
        row['user'] = user
        dt_string = str(fetch['date'])
        if dt_string in fetch and row[dt_string] != hr:
          raise Exception, "Contradiction: '%s' on '%s'" % (user, dt_string)
        row[dt_string] = hrs
        row.setdefault('Total', 0)
        row['Total'] += hrs
```

while generating below output

```
{u'ap': {'Total': 32, 'user': u'ap', '2011-08-17': 8, 
         '2011-08-16': 8, '2011-08-15': 8, '2011-08-14': 8,
         'up': 8, 'PL':8})
```

Getting key error,any help really appreciate

**Note** : Here you find two type of dicts one  {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}, and another is {'name': u'ab', 'total': 8, 'type': u'UP'},. difference between two is keys. in first dict you find **date key** and another dict **type key**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why *shouldn't* you get a KeyError?  You're asking for the value associated with `type` from the first row of `data` and there's no such key.

**EDIT:**

@agf says this is underhelpful, so let me try again.

The first line of `data` is

```
{'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8}
```

in the loop `fetch` (btw, variables should be named after nouns, not verbs; function names are verbs) is set to that first row and the following line is executed:

```
new_y = fetch['type']
```

Well, that line cannot succeed.  There is no entry for `type` in `fetch` so, as you have seen, Python throws a KeyError.  Change the data so there is such an entry or change the code so it doesn't need it.

Comment: but here two type of dicts are there one is {'date': datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), 'name': u'ab', 'total': 8} another is {'name': u'sst', 'total': 8, 'type': u'PL'}, means in one dict you will find date key and another is type key.

Comment: There are two types of dicts -- the program fails on the first kind, never gets to the second.  If "only half" your food were poisoned, would you expect to finish your plate?  I think maybe you just want to make two lists, one for each kind of dict, and process the lists separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing bounds checks for the "date" and "type" key:

```
for fetch in data:
    if "date" in fetch and "type" in fetch:
        user = fetch['name']
        hrs = fetch['total']
        row = results[user]
        new_y = fetch['type']
        row['type'] = fetch['l_total']
        row['user'] = user
        dt_string = str(fetch['date'])
        if dt_string in fetch and row[dt_string] != hr:
            raise Exception, "Contradiction: '%s' on '%s'" % (user, dt_string)
        row[dt_string] = hrs
        row.setdefault('Total', 0)
        row['Total'] += hrs
```

A better way to do this is check that each element in the dict has all the keys you'll need.

```
check = ["name", "total", "user", "type", "1_total", "date"]
for fetch in data:
    if all([i in fetch for i in check]):
        user = fetch["name"]
        . . .
```

Comment: Thank u for your help lysdexia, but i am not getting row[new_y] = fetch['l_total'], this values are not getting add to the dict